# converting a chi-square with more than one degree of freedom into a pearsons r

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power, pearson-r, kruskal-wallis-test

I want to run a power analysis for a study using correlations between two continuous variables. Previous research with the variable I am interested in used a Kruskal-Wallis test to look at differences between groups (by converting one variable into a grouping variable). To run my power analysis, I need to somehow convert the chi-square value $X^2(2)=10.44, p<.01$ to an r value. I understand that this is quite simple to do when the chi-square analysis involves only two groups, but is it possible to convert the chi-square to an r value when I have three groups?

Comment: The chi-square value you're asking about is the one from the Kruskal-Wallis test?

Comment: Yes it is. I also have the associated n value.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the earlier researchers split a continuous variable into 3 categories (a bad idea, but never mind) and you now want to somehow go back to the continuous version.

I don't know a way to do this directly from the $\chi^2$ value, but one thing you could do is assume a distribution for the variable that was split into 3 groups and then, within each group, assign a numeric score (using a suitable random number generator) and then use that.  I'd suggest trying several different sets of values and looking at them all as a sort of sensitivity analysis.

Comment: Are you familiar with the work around converting chi-squares with two groups into correlations- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2850938/ There seems to be a formula, but I can't access the books referenced to understand it.

Comment: No, but someone else here may be.